# Add a view multiple times in same container programmatically

Tags: android, view

The loop below works if run once (n = 1) but craches for multiple execution (n > 1).

IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. at line "containerLL.addView(divider);"

There is other views being created using "new" within this loop as well but not relevant to the problem at hand.

I am not sure if I need to make a "new" RelativeLayout
every time or what would be the correct way to fix it.

Thank you

divider.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/divider_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/plan_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

```
LinearLayout containerLL = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(mContainerViewId);
for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.divider_parent);
    View divider = li.inflate(R.layout.divider, rl);
    containerLL.addView(divider);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
LinearLayout containerLL = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(mContainerViewId);
for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    View divider = li.inflate(R.layout.divider, null, false);
    containerLL.addView(divider);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure if I need to make a "new" RelativeLayout every time

No, your problem is that you made `divider` a child of `rl`. It cannot be a child of `rl` and a child of `containerLL`. It has to be a child of one or the other.

Also, do not use `LayoutInflater.from(activity)`. Use `activity.getLayoutInflater()`. Otherwise, your styles and themes may get messed up.